# Issue in vtiger mail manager

Tags: php, mysql, crm, vtigercrm

In vtiger mail manager, when I delete any email, the previous email is automatically hidden. But after refreshing the page, the hidden email shows again.

[image: mail image]

Comment: Maybe give some details as to what you would expect, rather than just stating what happens.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.